# Are there raspberry pis small enough to be a smart watch?

Tags: raspbian, case

I want to build my own smartwatch with rasbipan, and i want to know if there exist raspberry pis or ardiunos small enough to fit on someones wrist.the biggesr issue for me is height.

Comment: Does a pip-boy qualify as a watch?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there [are](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-pipboy-3000/overview) ;) - and 3D-printed parts are pretty light.

The limiting factor is the battery. The Raspberry Pi (no matter which model) draws too much power to be usable as a smartwatch with a light battery.

[image]

Comment: That is so cool :)  +1

Answer (score 2):

A slightly smaller smartwatch using a Pi Zero:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=226470

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah - that could go on my bike!  +1